# Combining Columns row-wise R

Tags: r

I  have a matrix of values:

```
x<-matrix(rnorm(8),nrow=2,ncol=4,byrow=T)
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]      [,4]
[1,] -0.1048800  0.4437521 -0.7768075 0.2820776
[2,]  0.0700801 -0.4621662 -0.7877975 0.4933406
```

I'd like to make it look like this:

```
           [,1]      
[1,] -0.1048800
[2,]  0.0700801
[3,]  0.4437521
[4,] -0.4621662
[5,] -0.7768075
[6,] -0.7877975
[7,]  0.2820776
[8,]  0.4933406
```

I tried:

```
  temp<-c()
  for(l in 1:ncol(x)){
    temp<-rbind(temp,as.x[,l])
  }
```

but it wont make it work. any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just `matrix(x,8,1)`?

```
x<-matrix(rnorm(8),nrow=2,ncol=4,byrow=T)
> matrix(x,8,1)
           [,1]
[1,] -1.2735095
[2,] -0.8340542
[3,] -1.0982551
[4,]  0.8774815
[5,]  1.0443129
[6,] -0.1672568
[7,] -0.3545977
[8,] -1.2148138
```

Or as thelatemail notes, the more general `matric(x,ncol = 1)`.

Comment: Maybe `matrix(x,prod(dim(x)),1)` is a more general way to do it ;) +1

Comment: Or just - `matrix(x,ncol=1)` to make it generalisable.

Answer (score 4):

I think this does it:

```
x<-matrix(rnorm(8),nrow=2,ncol=4,byrow=T)
temp <- as.matrix(as.vector(x))
```

Comment: +1 I didn't see you had the same answer posted just before me. I'll edit my answer to take out what you have here

Answer (score 3):

Remembering a matrix is a vector with `dim` attributes...

you can alter the `dim` atributes directly to do...

```
dim(x) <- c(ncol(x)*nrow(x),1)
```

Comment: As you commented in my answer `prod(dim(x))` is a good alternative to `ncol(x)*nrow(x)` :) (+1)!!.

Answer (score 2):

A fancy way is using `attr` as in:

```
> set.seed(1)
> x<-matrix(rnorm(8),nrow=2,ncol=4,byrow=T)
> attr(x, "dim") <- c(prod(dim(x)), 1)
> x
           [,1]
[1,] -0.6264538
[2,]  0.3295078
[3,]  0.1836433
[4,] -0.8204684
[5,] -0.8356286
[6,]  0.4874291
[7,]  1.5952808
[8,]  0.7383247
```

Comment: `dim(x)<-` is just convenience shorthand for `attr(x,"dim")<-`! But +1 for use of `prod`. Should've thought of that. <facepalm>